# Proving that a function is linear using the directional directive

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ if we have

$f\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1 + v_1 \\
  a_2 + v_2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ = $f\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \end{pmatrix} + [Df(a)]   \large\vec{v}$

for all $a,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

then $f$ is linear.

Obviously the derivative is linear, not sure how that can help me here though, since I can't see any immediate use for the equality $[Df(a)]   \large\vec{v}$ $=$ $[Df(a\vec{ v})]$

Comment: One approximates a differentiable function by a linear function; what happens if that function equals this approximation? Answer: It is linear. :) **Hint:** Try to verify the linearity axioms.

Comment: Well, that's akin to showing $D[f(a)]\vec{v} = f(\begin{matrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{matrix}$ 

And to be honest, I'm not sure how to do that without f being linear..

Comment: in the first line there may be a typo: should be $\to$ rather than $\mapsto$

Answer (score 0):

You have $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^2,f(x)=f(0)+Df(0)x$ which looks linear to me.

Comment: is showing only 0 work slike that sufficient to show its linear?